# how to take screen shot from camera view?

Tags: ios

Friends and sirs

Thanks for taking time for me.

I want to take screen shots in app.

Now i;m trying to use following codes.

```
- (UIImage *)captureView:(UIView *)view {
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);

    [view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

But problem is that it only takes black screens when I am on camera mode.

This above code works perfectly in other views excepting camera view.

I want to take screen shots of camera view.

Simply I can use `UIGetScreenImage` to get screen shot of camera view, but this is non-public api and if I use this then the app can't upload to appstore on xcode 4.3.

How can I do that?

Any idea for this?

If then this will be great help for me.

thanks again.

Comment: If you mean that the camera view is black, that is because it's in a separate window.  You need to merge the windows together.  There's an Apple tech doc that tells you how to do this, but I can't find it just now.

Comment: Why merge windows if you could just create your own [AVCaptureSession](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?  The docs are quite helpful as to how to do it.